# After implementing background location updates FCM gone mad and are sent continuously without programmed trigger

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, core-location

I am creating simple chat app using Firebase. My database has node for messages, and when user gets message from another user - cloud function monitors changes and sends firebase cloud message to user's token. UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate was properly implemented in AppDelegate.
Everything worked fine until I began to implement background location updates with CoreLocation locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() method. I instantiate locationManager also in AppDelegate.
My app saves current location to UserDefaults(), then updates location, compares it to saved location in UserDefaults and if it is far from saved location or was not saved to database for certain period of time, current location is saved to Firebase database and is updated at UserDefaults().
After running app I started to get notifications from Firebase (both in foreground and in background) which are last 5-8 (then up to 58 at a time) messages that user got new message.

I tried to understand what triggers these FCMs but only could print notification.description to console

I tried
     func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    }

but it didn't work

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import GoogleMobileAds
import CoreLocation


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
   lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        return locationManager
    }()

    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        self.startLocationService()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.registerForPushNotifications()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests(    )

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
        print("Registered with device token \(tokenParts.joined())")

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("notification is \(notification.description)")

       completionHandler([.sound])

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Received notification \(response.notification)")

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if application.applicationState == .active {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        } else {
            let numberOfUnreadMessages = userInfo["count"] as! String
            if let badgeNumber = Int(numberOfUnreadMessages) {
                application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber
            }

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func startLocationService() {
        print("Starting location services in AppDelegate")
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {

            activateLocationServices()

        } else {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    private func activateLocationServices() {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            activateLocationServices()
        } else {
            print("CLAuthorizationStatus is notDetermined")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error happened while getting current location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.first
        print("AppDelegate got location")

        if defaults.value(forKey: "currentLatitude") == nil {
            let currentLatitude = currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let currentLongtitude = currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude
            let currentAltitude = currentLocation?.altitude
            let timeStamp: Double = Double(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

            defaults.set(currentLatitude, forKey: "currentLatitude")
            defaults.set(currentLongtitude, forKey: "currentLongtitude")
            defaults.set(currentAltitude, forKey: "currentAltitude")
            defaults.set(timeStamp, forKey: "locationUpdated")
            print("UserDefaults updated with current location")
        }

        saveLocationToDatabase()

    }

    func saveLocationToDatabase() {

        var previousLocation: CLLocation?
        var previuosTime: Double?

        guard let currentLocation = currentLocation, let currentUserUid = defaults.string(forKey: "uid") else { return }

        let previousLatitude = defaults.double(forKey: "currentLatitude")
        let previousLongtitude = defaults.double(forKey: "currentLongtitude")
        previuosTime = defaults.double(forKey: "locationUpdated")

        previousLocation = CLLocation(latitude: previousLatitude, longitude: previousLongtitude)
        let timeStamp: Double = Double(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

        if previousLocation != nil && previuosTime != nil {
            let distance = currentLocation.distance(from: previousLocation!)
            let time =  timeStamp - previuosTime!

            if distance < 100 && time < 60 {
                print("distance is \(distance), time is \(time)")
                print("No need to save location")
                return
            } else {
                self.saveChangesToDatabase()
            }
        } else {
            self.saveChangesToDatabase()
        }
    }

    func saveChangesToDatabase() {
        guard let currentLocation = currentLocation, let currentUserUid = defaults.string(forKey: "uid") else { return }
        let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid)
        usersRef.child("location").child("latitude").setValue(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        usersRef.child("location").child("longtitude").setValue(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        usersRef.child("location").child("altitude").setValue(currentLocation.altitude)
        let timeToSet: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
        usersRef.child("location").child("updated").setValue(timeToSet)

        print("Location saved to database")

        defaults.set(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, forKey: "currentLatitude")
        defaults.set(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, forKey: "currentLongtitude")
        defaults.set(currentLocation.altitude, forKey: "currentAltitude")
        defaults.set(timeToSet, forKey: "locationUpdated")
        print("UserDefaults updated with current location")

        self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
            if let city = placemark.locality, let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                let currentPlace = "\(city), \(state)"
                usersRef.child("location").child("currentPlace").setValue(currentPlace)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

My console is:

AppDelegate got location
distance is 0.00017503746557926585, time is 58.0
No need to save location
AppDelegate got location
Location saved to database
UserDefaults updated with current location
notification is ,, trigger: >>
notification is ,, trigger: >>

and so on....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is completely in Firebase Cloud Functions and it has nothing to do with CoreLocation services